# Свойство visible

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, я бы хотел спросить, на форме имеется 5 кнопок, и каждой кнопке соответствует картинка, при нажатии на Button1 отображается только первая картинка, при Button2 вторая, и так далее. Можно ли свойство `visible` объединить для допустим 2,3,4,5 картинки? Чтобы каждой не прописывать его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете процедуру/функцию (или как там это в Делфи называется), в которой показываете/скрываете картинки под нужными номерами. Затем просто вещаете эту функцию на нужную кнопку. 
Или же можно написать одну функцию для всех кнопок, но номера изображений, с которыми она должна работать, вычислять динамически исходя из номера(названия) кнопки, которая эту функцию вызвала.

Answer (score 0):

Пример обращения к нескольким компонентам сразу:

> for ilocal := 1 to 5 do 
> TImage(self.FindComponent('Image'+inttostr(ilocal))).Visible:=false;